# Google Analytics Universal Event Tracking Code Not working

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a image that links to another site in a HTML widget in the sidebar on my site and
I would like to track the clicks but for some reason it is not showing up in the `"Events"` tab on my analytics.

The code I am using is as follows...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-***my UA code***']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www.***the link I want to track***/) + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

<a href="http://www.***the link I want to track***/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Outgoing Links','NightMarket','advert']);"><img src="***The image i want to track***"width=318/a></a>
```

I managed to get this working a few months ago but stupidly misplaced the code I used.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Events won't show up right away in your standards reports. You need to wait at least 24 hours for it to appear. In the meantime  you can check your real time reports to see if the event shows up right after you trigger it.

Comment: By the way are you using Universal as in your title? Because your code is not using Universal analytics syntax. Or maybe you mean universal as in widely used or known.

Comment: Hi @nyuen and thanks for getting back to me. I am indeed using Google Universal Analytics. I have also had this code up for over 24 hours and still nothing has shown up.

Comment: You will need to use the UA library and syntax. Check your account for the correct tracking code. The event syntax also needs to change to use the ga object.

Comment: @nyuen I have found the correct tracking code. I am a little unsure of where I would place it in relation to the code above, Also I do i Change the syntax and UA Library

Comment: You would need to replace the code above with the Universal Analytics tracking code, which should be placed within the <head> tags of your page. For a WP site, I think you would place it in the header.php file of your theme. (Posting event syntax as an Answer to get the formatting.)

Answer (score 0):

Universal analytics event tracking code should look something like this, if triggered by onclick:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Outgoing links', 'Nightmarket', 'advert');"
```

Answer (score -2):

Google Analytics pageviews tracking were not working:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'Tracking ID', 'Domain');  // Replace with your property ID.
    ga('send', 'pageview','URL');
```

Please find the issues involved on the above...